# How to use the blenderpy module from Blender in (Anaconda) Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, blender

I've tried to install the module `bpy` (blenderpy) to be able to run python-scripts for Blender directly from Spyder IDE with Python 3.8.5. However, I can't seem to find a good solution for this.

I've tried to follow [this](https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy/wiki/Building) wiki on Github to use a build provided for `bpy version 2.82`. I installed every required program and tried to install `bpy` with `!pip install bpy --no-binary :all:` in the Spyder-console, like it was suggested in the wiki. Unfortunately, `bpy version 2.82` is not compatible with Windows Python 3.8.5:

```
in build_cmake
    raise Exception(f"{VERSION} bpy is not compatible with "
Exception: 2.82 bpy is not compatible with Windows Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit [...]
```

Otherwise the installation of bpy would probably have worked.

My question is now: Is there a more recent build for `bpy` which can be installed with `pip` and is compatible with (Anaconda) Spyder python 3.8.5? If not, which Anaconda-distribution of Python do I need to install in order to be compatible with bpy 2.82? How could you manually add modules (like bpy) to your Spyder IDE that aren't available in the Anaconda-Distribution of Python and can't be installed via anaconda.org?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The instructions you pointed to are for *building* `bpy`, not to install it. For that, please run `pip install bpy` but not inside Spyder because that can give you problems later on. Instead, please run it in the Anaconda prompt.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I already installed bpy inside Spyder ... :( How can I undo `pip install bpy && bpy_post_install` inside Spyder? With `pip uninstall bpy`? What problems will occure if you install bpy inside Spyder?

Comment: If things are working fine for you, then probably installation was ok. Otherwise, you'll need to remove your Python installation and recreate it again.

Comment: Until now, I did not experience any errors, but I will try to install new packages with Anaconda prompt. Thank you for the tip!